# Python and Kivy: How to update Image from memory?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi, kivy

I'm currently trying to display an image with kivy on a Raspbery Pi 4. The problem is that no image is shown on the Image widget. Also no Error or something else is given out to the terminal.

This is what I came up with in show_picture() in `.py` file:

```
image = camera.takePicture()
encode_param = [int(cv.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 95]
result, enc_img = cv.imencode('.jpg', image, encode_param)
data = io.BytesIO(enc_img)
texture_ = CoreImage(data, ext="jpg").texture
```

The `texture_` object was declared and initialized at class level with:

```
texture_ = StringProperty(None)
```

And in the `.kv` file I have following for the Image widget:

```
Image:
    id: imageView
    source: app.texture_
    allow_stretch: True
```

I want the image to be updated via this method so that the gui shows the latest taken image. If someone has a different approach I'm also happy with it.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: messed something up when copying code

Comment: What happens if you replace `source: app.texture_` with `texture:  app.texture_`?